# how to prove this matrix is orthogonal

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices

how can I prove matrix H is orthogonal?
Don't know where should I start with.

$$H = I - 2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}$$

[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eHZW.png)

Comment: $H$ is known as a [Householder reflection matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint to get you started:

Evaluate $$\left(I-2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\right)^T\left(I-2\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\right)$$

Edit:

\begin{align}&I-4I\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}+4\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\\
&=I-4\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}+4\frac{v(v^Tv)v^T}{(v^Tv)^2}\\
&=I-4\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}+4\frac{(v^Tv)vv^T}{(v^Tv)^2}\\
&=I-4\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}+4\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}\\&=I\end{align}

Comment: Hi, I have tried that, and I make it here, then I don't know what to do next. could you please help me to take a look: [image of my solution](http://imgur.com/a/5t7Pe)

Comment: good job for reaching this far, I have edited the solution.

Comment: Hi, from the second line to the third line,in the third polynomial, I don't really know why it satisfy the  commutative law？ And in the second  polynomial,the denominator may should be $v^Tv$ .

Comment: oops, that's a typo, thanks.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand why $4\frac{v(v^Tv)v^T}{(v^Tv)^2}\\$ can be changed to $4\frac{(v^Tv)vv^T}{(v^Tv)^2}\\$ .

Comment: $v^Tv$ is a scalar right?

Comment: Okay ,I get it, $v$ and $v^T$ is a vector, their multiplication is a  scalar. I mistakenly thought v was a matrix before. Thanks for the help.

Comment: welcome, glad that it's solved. yup $v$ is a vector, if it's a matrix, we will have to worry about what does the denominator mean.